# How to plot character class monthly averages using the Dygraphs package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot monthly average data using the `dygraphs` package, but I continue to receive the "`Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'`" error. I realize this is because the function is looking for a date, but the "Month" column is a character class. Is there a way to change it so its recognized as a date for visualization purposes?

Here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dygraphs)

Period <- c("January 2015", "February 2015", "March 2015",
            "January 2016", "February 2016", "March 2016",
            "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017",
            "January 2018", "February 2018", "March 2018")

Month <- c("January", "February", "March",
           "January", "February", "March",
           "January", "February", "March",
           "January", "February", "March")

Dollars <- c(936, 753, 731, 
             667, 643, 588, 
             948, 894, 997, 
             774,745, 684)

dat <- data.frame(Period = Period, Month = Month, Dollars = Dollars)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  dplyr::select(Month, Dollars) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(AvgDollars = mean(Dollars))

dygraph(dat2) # This is where I receive the error shown above.
```

I'm able to get the right output (`dat2`), but I'm unable to plot the data using the `dygraphs` package.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make fake date from Month so `dygraph` will accept it then change the label format in `dygraph` (if it has one)?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Here's the answer:

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  dplyr::select(Month, Dollars) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(AvgDollars = mean(Dollars)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Month = match(Month, month.name)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(-Month))

dygraph(dat2)
```